# Wrapper libraries around J2ME apis

Tags: api, java-me

Are there any convinient wrapper libraries around somewhat inconvenient J2ME apis for working with PIM data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I see there aren't any. And this should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

JSR 75 apis should be enough, however your device should support that. Do you mean you want something like what [Floggy](http://floggy.sourceforge.net/) provides for persistence?

Comment: >> JSR 75 apis should be enough
Yep, it is enough, but it is cumbersome.